# MySQL select - return value if matches 2 values in same column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Any MySQL experts out there?

I have an auth script which passes a username to a MySQL query and should return the username if that username has %s2member% or return null if not s2member

Table name is usermeta

```
****user_id********meta_key********meta_value****
        1           nickname            jsmith
        1           capabilities        a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
        2           nickname            paule
        2           capabilities        a13:"s2member";}
        3           nickname            mike
        3           capabilities        a14:"free-member";}
        4           nickname            mrjones
        4           capabilities        a15:"s2member";}
        5           nickname            adam
        5           capabilities        aw7:"s2member";}
```

Due to the layout of this data, I have no idea how to get a query to return 'paule' (if he has s2member).

My question: Is a query even possible to return meta_value "paule" if he has LIKE "s2member" in another meta_value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exists` operator and correlate the two rows

```
SELECT meta_value
FROM   usertable a
WHERE  meta_key = 'nickname' AND
       meta_value = 'paule' AND -- EDITED IN: Just return paule
       EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   usertable b
               WHERE  a.user_id = b.user_id AND
                      b.meta_key = 'capabilities' AND
                      b.meta_value LIKE '%"s2member"%')
```

Comment: Thank you - this works, though I had to remove the double quotes from the LIKE when testing in webmin, not sure if a webmin issue as the other reply also has double quotes so, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I just realised, I think this would return every relevant user? I need just the one user returned who was specified in the query. Thanks though :)

Comment: @Paul You could add another condition for that - I've edited it in to my answer, check it out.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for helping me learn more about MySQL. Hopefully other people who land on this page via search engines will find this useful too, as I really struggled to find anything for my search string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self join against the table and match the rows by userid. Something like this:

```
select 
  u1.meta_value 
from 
  usermeta u1
join 
  usermeta u2 
on 
  u1.userid = u2.userid
where 
  u1.meta_value = '<username passed in>'
  and u1.meta_key = 'nickname'
  and u2.meta_key = 'capabilities'
  and u2.meta_value like '%"s2member"%'
```

Generally speaking, joins are considered to be slightly more performant than the equivalent sub-query, but in my opinion sub-queries are often more readable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I agree that the sub query is a bit more readable for a MySQL learner.  Many thanks

Comment: This is the correct answer but due to my low reputation I'm not sure if I can mark it. Thanks a lot for the help. This has taken many, many hours from me until now! Time for a beer, cheers to you! :)